# Mysql: store query result to separate tamporary/virtual table

Tags: mysql, sql

**What I want:** I want to handle each row of result in separate query.

**What I have now:** `SELECT field1, field2 INTO @field1, @field2 FROM [QUERY]`.

**Problem:** If `[QUERY]` returns more than one result I'll get an exception.

**Question: [main]:** How can I store the result into table?.

**Question: [sub]:** how can I execute separate query for each row of result table?

**I.E:**

```
SET result_table = SELECT field1, field2 INTO @field1, @field2 FROM [QUERY]
For each row of result_table do QUERY2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a cursor?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sample_procedure
BEGIN
    -- We need this variable to identify the end of our procedure
    DECLARE finished_flag INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    -- These are variables for the fields you have, match the types.
    DECLARE field1 varchar(100);
    DECLARE field2 int;
    DECLARE field3 datetime;

    -- declare cursor for our select
    DECLARE run_foreach_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT
        field1,
        field2
    FROM [QUERY];

    -- declare NOT FOUND so we know when we've run out of results
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished_flag = 1;

    -- Open the cursor
    OPEN run_foreach_cursor;

    run_foreach_content: LOOP

        -- Put fields list on this line, this is where they go.
        FETCH run_foreach_cursor INTO field1, field2;

        IF finished_flag = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE run_foreach_content;
        END IF;

        -- Do your query here.
        INSERT INTO [tbl2]
        VALUES
           (
              field1,
              field2 + 7
           );

    -- Marks the end of our loop
    END LOOP run_foreach_content;

    -- Close the cursor so MySQL can free up the query attached to it. 
    CLOSE run_foreach_cursor;

END $$

DELIMITER ;

CALL sample_procedure();
```

Comment: mysql worbench doesn't know what is DECLARE keyword

Comment: @V_B the [Declare](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-local-variable.html) and [Fetch](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fetch.html) keywords are documented in MySQL 5.0, what version are you running?

Comment: `innodb 5.5.37`, `protocol version 10`

Comment: My mistake, Declare is only used in stored procedures, edit in place.

Comment: You can't use cursors outside of Stored procedures in MySQL, it's not possible, I'll be wrapping it in a SPROC and calling it at the end, hope that's OK.

Comment: You've written nice answer and maybe someone else will benefit from it. May you replace `simple_procedure` by `simple_procedure()` please?